# Explosive Lightning?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want it so that when lightning strikes the ground, it explodes the ground, how can I do this with just command blocks without using behavior packs or mods? Even if the command is long, I would really like it to be short as possible though.

If this is impossible, how do I make it so that if I throw a snowball, it makes lightning strike wherever the snowball lands and causes an explosion, without it summoning TNT if possible so that the explosion isn't delayed?

Comment: Do you want all lightning bolts to behave this way or do you simply want to summon a lightning bolt that behaves this way?

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's a similar situation as in MCJava: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/362025/171580 But it might not be, maybe lightnings are actual entities in MCBE.

Comment: Yes, all lightning bolts behave this way, even if the lightning bolt is summoned if possible. Basically changing all the lightning bolts.

Comment: I did a little research, they can be spawned as entities but I am unsure if you can actually edit the entire behavior. If you can could you provide how to change the entire lightning behavior to become explosive on impact? But if you can't perhaps just a snowball that summons a lightning bolt and a couple of TNT at the bottom of the lightning bolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a repeating command block that has this command:
`/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ [block ground is made of] [tile data] /summon lightning_bolt ~ ~ ~`

then in a attached chain command block put this:
`execute @e[type=lightning_bolt] ~ ~ ~  /summon ender_crystal`

then add a final chain command block that does this `/execute @e[type=ender_crystal] ~ ~ ~ /summon arrow ~ ~0.5 ~`
then you should get a near instant explosion
but you would also want another command to kill the snowball after impact, best using a conditional chain command block